# Web service do not return current Windows user name

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, asmx

This is the function that I use in web service for getting current windows user.

```
 <WebMethod()> _
  Function User() As String
        Dim p() As String = Split(My.User.Name, "\")
        Dim p1 As String = p(1)
        Return p1
    End Function
```

When I run service on localhost it realy return current windows user name!
The problem is when i run service from remote PC, in that case I got nothing from this function. What is problem with this service, and how I can get name of Windows user?

Thanks!

Comment: No i use this function:

 Function GetUserName() As String
        If TypeOf My.User.CurrentPrincipal Is WindowsPrincipal Then
           ' The application is using Windows authentication.  
           ' The name format is DOMAIN\USERNAME. 
            Dim parts() As String = Split(My.User.Name, "\")
            Dim username As String = parts(1)
            Dim domain As String = parts(0)
            Return My.User.Name
        Else
                Return My.User.Name
        End If
    End Function

But when I run it from remote computer I am getting HTTP 500 Internal server error!

Answer (score 4):

Which do you expect it to return: the identity of the *caller*? or the identity of the service account that is running the web-service?

In most cases the *windows* identity would depend on how the server is configured; is it using impersonation? Plus are you passing the callers identity over when calling the service? For example, `UseDefaultCredentials` or `Credentials`. And is the service configured to *recognise* the users claims?

Generally I try *not* to use impersonation; it requires elevation at the server, doesn't support all environments, and can have a big impact on the effectiveness of pooling - so I wouldn't expect the *windows* identity to flow, but if you are passing the callers identity in *some* form I might expect the "principal" (`Thread.CurrentPrincipal`) to represent the caller.

I can't remember from asmx, but with WCF you can write your own code to setup the principal from your own authentication scheme if you want.

Comment: Thanks for response! 
I have this like situation: Web service is set on server! I just need when client computer run this service, that client get windows logon user name from server computer! I really don't no what is  problem i am able to get Computer name of server but not user name. I suppose that problem is somewhere in security settings!

Comment: @Comii - in IIS, this is the identity of the App-Pool that is hosting the application.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
using System.Security.Principal;

[WebMethod()]
public string userName()
{
    return User.Identity.Name.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the identity the current thread is running under by the below line of code:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name
```

Comment: Thanks for response! It's return noting when it run from remote computer, just like my code!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
string _userName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```